# Passing arguments between Fragments that are inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm working with different Fragments that are hosted by a ViewPager.

The main purpose of doing this is because I need to convert a paper form into a digital form, and for user-friendly purposes, I decided to let the user swipe between all the fragments and complete each of them until the end of the form.

My goal is to construct an object at the end of the latest swiped fragment, so, at that time I will have all the data coming from the below fragments.

I have researched and found that I can use `setArguments()` to pass a bundle of data from each fragment to the next until the end, and this is a great idea since if the user wants to come back, they can change some arguments and keep the process of swiping until the end, and, at the last fragment, I will have all the arguments from all the fragments to create a unique object containing all the data that represents the entire form.

This is what I have tried

First I created a simple `ViewPager` adapter to switch between different fragments when I swipe

### MyPagerAdapter

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fm:FragmentManager): FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when(position){
            0 -> FragmentA.newInstance()
            1 -> FragmentB.newInstance()
            2 -> FragmentC.newInstance()
            else -> {
                FragmentA()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }
}
```

Then I just use this adapter with my viewpager at my MainActivity

### MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity(), MainContract.MainView {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setupViewPager()
    }

    override fun setupViewPager() {
        viewPager.adapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        viewPager.disableScroll(true)
        selectIndex(0)
    }

    override fun selectIndex(newIndex: Int) {
        viewPager.currentItem = newIndex
    }

    override fun getFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager).getItem(position)
    }

}
```

And this is where I need to pass arguments from **FragmentA** to **FragmentB**

### FragmentA

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): FragmentA = FragmentA()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        fab_continue.setOnClickListener {

            val name = etxt_name.text.toString().trim()
            val phone = etxt_phone.text.toString().trim()

            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("name",name)
            bundle.putString("phone",phone)

            (activity as MainActivity).getFragment(1).arguments = bundle
            (activity as MainActivity).selectIndex(1)
        }

    }
```

Here I asume that

```
(activity as MainActivity).getFragment(1).arguments = bundle
```

gets and inflate the next fragment, this fragment is **FragmentB** and pass the arguments to it

While

```
(activity as MainActivity).selectIndex(1)
```

Just swipe to the next page with the **FragmentB**

### The Problem

Now, the issue is that when the app launches, **getArguments** from **FragmentB** is immediately executed but I have not even swiped to it, or pass the arguments from **FragmentA**, and that generates null to **getArguments**.

With the above code I did, I thought that after pressing my fab button from **FragmentA**, the `getFragment(1)` method will instantiate my **FragmentB**, but it seems is not doing what it should do.

So at my `FragmentB`

```
class FragmentB: Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): FragmentB = FragmentB()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("Argumentos:",""+arguments?.getString("name")) //This returns null
    }
```

`arguments?.getString("name")` returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended and simple solution is using `ViewModel` as described in [View Model guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). Something likes:

```
MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(yourActivity).get(MyViewModel.class); // in your activity
// in your fragments
model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
model.yourFunctionToChangeData(yourData);
// observer result in other fragments
model.getSelected().observe(this, { yourData ->
       // Update the UI.
    });
```

By using `ViewModel`, the model is created once in Activity and shared between all your fragments inside your `Activity`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the default Factory Method template. Check these checkbox when you creating a `Fragment`
[image: Check these checkbox when you creating a <code>Fragment</code>]

After that, you can see the template with the constructor `newInstance()`

create the fragment in activity like this

```
    BlankFragment.newInstance("First Thing", "Second String")
```

and for the `Fragment`, the access ways are generated

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1) 
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }
}
```

now you can have those values `param1` and `param2`.

If you want to use the constructor way:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

  public BlankFragment()
  {} // Empty Constructor required

  public BlankFragment(int someParam)
  {
     // your constructor
  }
}
```

This also works, but you'll have 2 constructors while you can use only one factory method (and it's auto generated by AndroidStudio!)

Comment: But there is no way to do it the way i'm doing it? I think that the factory is the same as the one I have but just settings argumente to the newinstance

Comment: You can also pass those values in your constructors, too. Then it should looks like `FragmentB("String1")`

Comment: Thanks for your response I finally solved it without the viewpager and implemented the fragments inflation from each fragment, thanks